# Can not add new product

Tags: magento-1.7, product, configurable-product, new-products

I cannot add new products in Magento because de main options are not showing after clicking on "Add new product", I attach an screenshot. As you can see see in the left menu there are missing several options. What happens? Thanks. (magento 1.7.0.2)

[image]

Comment: Are you logged in as an admin ?

Comment: Hi, thank for your comment. Of course, I'm logged in as full Admin.

Comment: Did you recently try add a product attribute via a script or installed a new module ?

Comment: It could be because of a product attribute?

Comment: Yes it happens if a script that is supposed to add a product attribute is not properly written. Did you double check the attribute set to ensure everything was there ?

Comment: It would be very helpful if you'd set your admin to English and add the screenshot again, in English

Comment: Done @7ochem, as you can see I miss several tabs.

Comment: go to index.php something around line 76 there should be
`ini_set('display_errors', 1);`
and
`Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);`
umcomment the ini_set and copy the developer mode outside the if statement
Afterwards reload and copy the error / exception here :)

Comment: The thing is that I'm no receiving any error, I just have missing tabs. I receive the errors when I try to save the product but it is a normal error: Missing keys, because I cannot write a name, description or SKU...

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the attribute set is borked. Try the following:

- add a simple product using the Default attribute set and see if you're still missing the options
- edit some random products and see if you have all the options visible in the left menu
- go to `Catalog -> Attributes -> Manage Attribute Sets` (exact path might vary depending on the version of Magento) and check the Default attribute set as well as the attribute set that you used in the screenshot; check that the attribute sets have groups with attributes in the Groups section: [image]

The options form the menu that are missing are actually attribute groups; the relations between attribute sets, attribute groups and attributes are: 1 attribute set has many attribute groups which in turn has many attributes. The symptoms of the issue you're having are consistent with a broken relationship between the attribute set and the attribute groups which could be caused by an error in an upgrade script that manipulates either attribute sets, or attribute groups or even attributes.