# can not add product in admin panel

Tags: magento-1.9, product

can not add product in admin panel.

Hi to all,

I have a bad and big problem with my magento. I was using Magento 1.9.2.2. After adding about 4 thousand products and 576 attributes in add new product page, I don't see tabs of attributes.

I use Default or other custom attribute set for my product but I think my Main system attribute are broken in link to attribute set but there have all of default attributes in My attribute sets.
screen shot from my add new product page:

there was same problem that was asked in magento stackexchange, but that was no answer :
[Can not add new product](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/83893/can-not-add-new-product)

After that i installed fresh magento 1.9.2.4 without anything and after that transferred my product, orders, customers, attributes and attribute sets to new shop. Every thing was good for 1 month but after that today again have this problem.

Any body can help me?

I have installed 9 extensions in 1 month and don't installed anything new.

Comment: have you got any error in /var/system.log?

Answer (score 0):

In this section no error [image]

I do not think there is anything relevant to this section.